# unable to update habtm table on create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a sessions model and users model, where they have habtm relationship. I have a scenario where all users can be a part of session or only particular users can be part of that session.

```
def attendees=(emails)
```

#ToDo Refactor this piece of code

if emails == 'All'

```
  emails = User.all.collect(&:email)
```

end

```
raise ArgumentError, 'Input should be an array of emails' unless emails.is_a?(Array)
raise ArgumentError, 'Input Array of emails is empty' if emails.empty?


self.users = []
emails.each do |email|
  user = User.create_retrieve_user({:email => email})
  self.users << user unless self.users.include?(user)
end
```

end

when I pass All from the front end this is not creating any entries in the sessions_users table. This works fine for update method and when I pass any particular email_ids to attendees=(email).

what could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code which is updating the sessions for the user?
Ideally for a HABTM relation, you need to link the related tables. For example:

```
user = User.create_retrieve_user({:email => email})
user.sessions = Session.create_session
user.save
```